# Python/rpy2 does not recognize %>% pipe in r code

Tags: python, r, dplyr, rpy2

I have a Python script that will pass dataframes into an R package and get the results.  The R script works as expected in R studio.

However I cannot get it to wokr when executing through python/rpy2.

```
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in ataframe d%>% dplyr::rename(domain = Domain, variable = Variable,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
```

Is there a way to get this to work when executing through python?  Rewriting the code to not use %>% is working but will require a lot of rewriting that I would prefer to avoid if possible.

I've tried making sure the dplyr library is in every script.  I've confirmed its installed prior to running the python script.

I have not found any examples of this issue while using rpy2/python.

Comment: have you loaded `library(dplyr)`

Comment: i have loaded library(dplyr) in the R package.  The code runs fine in rstudio but does not run when executed in python.

I do not have any R experience.  I am trying to get a package to integrate with a python project so all of this is new to me

Comment: Can you assign the operator as ``%>%` <- dplyr::`%>%`` (backquotes around the operator).   Or may be `#' @importFrom magrittr %>%` if it is for creating a package

Comment: If you are using R version 4.1 or later you can use `|>` instead.

Comment: @GregorThomas that seems to have done the trick in the quickest way for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`%>%` is from the `magrittr` package. If you have R version 4.1 or later you can use the native `|>` pipe instead.